# Wrap directive element with html

Tags: angularjs

I'm wanting to setup a directive to speed up some form building I'm doing. Is it possible if I write an element like this

```
<input type="text" name="someName" placeholder="A Placeholder" form-title="Some Name" />
```

It ends up being renders as such

```
<div class="formKey">
    Some Name
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="someName" placeholder="A Placeholder" form-title="Some Name" />
</div>
```

So basically it justs wraps the element the directive is on with some html. I've seen angulars directive options `template` for changing the html, and `transclude` for keeping internal html, but I can't find anything for doing this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you were on the right path with `transclude`.

Try something like:

```
app.directive('customInput', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      transclude: element,
      scope: { form-title: '@' },
      templateUrl: 'page.html'
    };
  });
```

Page.html :

```
<div class="formKey">
    {{form-title}}
</div>
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

And call it from your HTML :

```
<input customInput type="text" name="someName" placeholder="A Placeholder" form-title="Some Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do something link this, however you need to add a custom directive as shown below:

```
    <custom-input form-title="Some Name">
        <input type="text" name="someName" placeholder="A Placeholder"/>
    </custom-input>
```

Then add a directive code,

```
    myApp.directive('customInput', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope : {
            formTitle : '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'my-wrapper.html'
      };
    });
```

And my-wrapper.html is

```
<div class="formKey">
    {{formTitle}}
</div>
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

Hope this helps!!!